# PropertyChangedCallback fired before WPF attached behavior gets attached

Tags: wpf, xaml, attached-properties, attachedbehaviors

I'm working with a custom WPF behavior (the one from System.Windows.Interactivity) showing a couple of dependency properties, one of those being a string. The behavior also overrides `OnAttached` in order to grab a reference to its `AssociatedObject` UI control.

When that attached property is data-bound to viewModel and is later changed (and notified) at some point, everything seems fine: *OnAttached* has been fired "at the beginning", and later the *PropertyChangedCallback* gets fired.

The issue I see is when the property is not bound, but set to a "static" value in XAML. In this case the *PropertyChangedCallback* gets fired before *OnAttached*, when the behavior has yet to know its associated UI control and basically cannot do anything in reaction to that property changing.

I guess I'm missing something on how things should be done in this case. Any help in understanding this is appreciated. TA

**EDIT**
Showing here some code, if that might be helpful in this case:

```cs
public class SomeUIControlBehaviour : Behavior<SomeUIControl>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        _attachedUIControl = this.AssociatedObject;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        _attachedUIControl = null;
    }

    private SomeUIControl _attachedUIControl;

    private void MessageChanged()
    {
        if (_attachedUIControl != null)
        {
            // do something on it
        }
        else
        {
            // bummer!
        }
    }

    // Text property + dependency property

    public string Message
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value); }
    }

    private static string _defaultMessage = String.Empty;

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Message.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Message", 
            typeof(string), typeof(SomeUIControlBehaviour),
            new PropertyMetadata(_defaultMessage, MessagePropertyChanged));

    private static void MessagePropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs evt)
    {
        //Debug.WriteLine("MessagePropertyChanged, on " + sender.GetType().Name + ", to value " + evt.NewValue);

        SomeUIControlBehaviour behaviour = sender as SomeUIControlBehaviour;

        if (behaviour == null) 
        {
            Debug.Fail("Message property should be used only with SomeUIControlBehaviour");
            return;
        }

        behaviour.MessageChanged();
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that one simple answer could be:  
when behavior gets attached, just check if the property has already a value (maybe different than default) and in that case do what the PropertyChangedCallback was supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment, one simple answer could be:

when behavior gets attached, just check if the property has already a value (maybe different than default) and in that case do what the `PropertyChangedCallback` was supposed to do.